# Wordpress multisite: reusing domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, multisite

Good day

I have a WP Multisite in which a site was running. The administrators decided they would revamp the site, and they did it in a provisional subdirectory so that the original site would be available while the changes took place. So this is the current structure:

- mymultisite.com

  - mysite.com
  - mymultisite.com/mysitebeingremade

Now that the site changes have been finished, I would like to attach the domain name to the revamped site. So, I try to disable the site currently attached to mysite.com, change its domain to a different one, and attach the domain name to the revamped one. So from the sites configuration I make the following changes in Sites > Edit site > Site info:

- mymultisite.com

  - mysite.com -> mymultisite.com/mysite
  - mymultisite.com/mysitebeingremade -> mysite.com

But it seems as if the domain name keeps pointing to the old site. What am I doing wrong? Or is it just impossible to reuse a domain name previously used in a multisite, but not in use anymore, for a new site?

I guess that I can just overwrite the original sites with the one with the changes, but I think it is too much hassle for a seemingly simple task.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I sorted it out.

It seems that, when you delete a site from the multisite, it doesn't get deleted from the database. Specifically, one entry remains in the table [prefix]_domain_mapping in which the fields 'id' and 'blog_id' are still pointing to the old site that was linked to that domain.

By changing those two fields to the id of the new site that will be using that domain name, and provided that all the changes have been made to the configuration of that site in the site configuration to use that domain for that site, it should work ok.

Thank you,